# My while loop seems to be restarting except when I insert a negative number?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

my while loop works fine until I input a negative number, what am I doing wrong? After I input a negative number, the loop stops and the code finishes executing. I want it to restart the full while loop so I can continue inputting until budgetRemaining hits 0. I appreciate the help, thanks!

```
Scanner enterPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    double budgetRemaining = 100;
    double itemPrice;

    System.out.println("Please enter price of item:");
    itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble();

    if (itemPrice < budgetRemaining) {
        budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;

        if (itemPrice < 0) {
            budgetRemaining += itemPrice;
            System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount.");

        } while (budgetRemaining > 0 && itemPrice >= 0) {
            System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
            System.out.println(itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble());

            if (itemPrice < budgetRemaining) {
                budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;

                if (itemPrice < 0) {
                    budgetRemaining += itemPrice;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
                }


            } else if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
            }

            if (itemPrice == budgetRemaining) {
                budgetRemaining = 0;
                System.out.println("You have reached your maximum budget. Thank you for shopping with us!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have way too many if statements. Think about the logic and try to see how you can reduce the number of conditional checks. You should have a while loop outside and then a few conditions inside the while loop to determine the behavior. You can kind of get it to work by fixing the condition on the while loop but that is not the best solution.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: I'm familiar with what it is but I don't exactly know how to use it. I suppose I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `&& itemPrice >= 0` criteria from your while loop if you do not want it to stop when `itemPrice` is less than 0.